# Adding Multiple MongoDb Collections in app.seeting file and how can they be called and used from service class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I having multiple collections such as one for users, courses, action plans and diseases how can i add them in appsettings.json and how to call them separately in service class when utilizing them

appsetting.json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "local",
    "CollectionName": "startup_log"
  }
}
```

Start Up File

```
services.AddScoped<DataInterface, DataService>();
services.Configure<AppDbConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
```

AppDbConfig Class

```
public class AppDbConfig
    {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string CollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

DataService Class

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<startup_log> startupLogs;
    public DataService(IOptions<AppDbConfig> settings)
    {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
    IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.DatabaseName);
    startupLogs = database.GetCollection< startup_log >(settings.Value.CollectionName);
    }
```

Start Up Log File

```
public class startup_log
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("hostname")]
        public string HostName { get; set; } = null!;
        [BsonElement("startTime")]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; } 
        [BsonElement("startTimeLocal")]
        public string StartTimeLocal { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to support only different collections or can they also be hosted on different servers or stored in different databases?

Comment: Do you mean [Inject IOptions from array of sub-options to Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845560/inject-ioptions-from-array-of-sub-options-to-service/71879144#71879144) ?

Comment: Support only different collections present on the same database and hosted within the same server @Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to support different collection, you could rename the `CollectionName` property in your configuration and create a property for each collection that you need to support, e.g.

```
public class AppDbConfig
{
  public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;
  public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;
  public string StartupLogsCollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
  public string OtherCollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

---

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "local",
    "StartupLogsCollectionName": "startup_log",
    "OtherCollectionName": "otherDocs"
  }
}
```

In your `DataService`, you can then use the different collection names when setting up the service:

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<startup_log> startupLogs;
private readonly IMongoCollection<OtherType> otherColl;

public DataService(IOptions<AppDbConfig> settings)
{
  MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
  IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.DatabaseName);
  startupLogs = database.GetCollection<startup_log>(settings.Value.StartupLogsCollectionName);
  otherColl = database.GetCollection<OtherType>(settings.Value.OtherCollectionName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Markus that was really useful its working fine now. Thanks again in advance